# format text in richtextbox vb6

Tags: vb6, format, richtextbox, rtf

I need to format text to be outputted in a richtextbox, for example, just doing this in wordpad

> *Hello* world

gives this in notepad when i opend the richtext document in notepad

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Arial;}}
{\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.15.1515;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\i\f0\fs20 hello\i0  world\par
}
```

I want to format text incode, and display the formated text in richtextbox, just like the example i did in wordpad above.

Is there a simple way to achieve this without manipulation the richtext format?

thanks

Comment: Can you be more clear?  It isn't clear what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to programmatically create RTF?  Are you trying to get plain-text from RTF?  You say "just doing this" and show some text, but don't describe what you are doing at all.  You say "gives this", but you don't say what gives what, and then you ask a question about achieving something, which doesn't indicate that you want to do what you have shown, or something else.

Comment: @brad i added more information

Comment: you still aren't clear... you are trying to create RTF programmatically?

Comment: @brad `I want to format text in code, and display the formated text in richtextbox`. **Yes** create RTF programmatically?

Comment: Alright, so how do you know what to format in what way?  You want to italicize the first world of every input?

Comment: @Smith, I have to go with Brad, you are a little unclear what you want to do. If you are eventually displaying text in a rich text box anyway, it is by far easier to use the properties and methods of the richtextbox control to format the text as you add it.

Comment: i will be italicizing the first two words, e.g _First_ _two_ will be italics. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the RichTextBox control itself to manipulate the contents, like this:

```
RichTextBox1.Text = "Hello world"  'Set the text
RichTextBox1.SelStart = 0  'Select the first 5 characters
RichTextBox1.SelLength = 5
RichTextBox1.SelItalic = True 'Set the selection to italic
```

However, you need to know exactly the position of the text you want to format, so if you want to generate a dynamic document, this is difficult.  This seems designed for you to be able to put formatting buttons on your form and let the user format the text he is looking at by selecting portion of it and choose format.
If you want to create dynamic documents you'll probably want to use a library to generate the RTF document and display the results.  There are some RTF libraries out there, both for ActiveX and .NET.

Comment: I haven't used this myself, but RTFWriter looks promising if you need ActiveX:  http://www.tabogasoftware.com/id8.htm.  There are more options if you can use .Net, Google gives many good looking results if you use the keywords: rtf library